# I want to get an array random elemet from an intial array

Tags: javascript

I have an initial `array1 =[{id:"0",a:"4",b:"6"},{id:"1",a:"r",b:"8"},{id:"2",a:"8",b:"9"}]`
I want another array that contains random elements from the intial array

```
randomArray=[{id:"0",a:"4",b:"6"},{id:"2",a:"8",b:"9"}]
```

how can i do it?

Comment: your solution can be ```Math.random``` based. You have not described if the length of ```randomArray``` is less than the length of ```array1``` (otherwise you would have element repetition)

Comment: Pls, write more detail: how length of intial array, randomArray

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Math.random()` like below;

```js
const array1 =[{id:"0",a:"4",b:"6"},{id:"1",a:"r",b:"8"},{id:"2",a:"8",b:"9"}];
const filtered = array1.filter(() => Math.random() > 0.5);
console.log(filtered);
```

*Note: The probability that every individual item is chosen is 50% in my solution.*

Comment: this has `50%` probability to return an empty array, use recursion to make sure it return at least one

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair Thanks but there is no requirement that the results should have at least one item.

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair And the probability to return an empty array is `0.5 ^ array.length`. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const random = (array, length) => array.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, length);

const mock = [
  { id: "0", a: "4", b: "6" },
  { id: "1", a: "r", b: "8" },
  { id: "2", a: "8", b: "9" },
  { id: "3", a: "8", b: "9" }
];

console.log(random(mock, 2))
console.log(random(mock, 3))
console.log(random(mock, 4))
```